# Can't get Grub to load windows after using Boot repair

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have windows 7 64bit, installed on pc, installed ubuntu 14.04lts, everything looked and worked great, until I went to load windows, and would just get a purple window.
I found the information to repair this with Boot-repair. It worked & am now able to boot up Windows, but only Windows. :/
A little advice in simpleton words on how to get dual boot working properly at this point?

Comment: Hard to know. I am going to guess that you have to select which OS to boot in your bios. Post the link / url you were given in boot repair

Comment: Via the Boot-Repair graphical tool
Run Boot-Repair from a liveCD, click "Advanced options", tick "Restore MBR", click "Apply".

http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1353333605.png

This will automatically restore a generic syslinux MBR, and set the boot flag on the Windows boot partition. This will also tell you if the Windows bootsector needs repair (see this tutorial).

Comment: I am familiar with boot repair and grub, but you have not provided sufficient information to give guidance. Obviously re-installing grub did not fix the problem. So either it is a problem with your bios (select which OS to boot from your bios) or your configuration. For the second we need the link boot-repair gives when it runs.

Comment: Hi bodhi, thanks for the info & help so far. Here is the link I have gotten http://paste.ubuntu.com/9925980/

Comment: so, what happens when you boot, enter your bios, and select which OS to boot ? My guess is this is the problem.

Comment: When I bootup grub comes on, but when I select windows 7 it doesn't go to windows, just hangs.

Comment: You select windows in your bios before you even get to the grub menu

Comment: I don't understand. In bios startup only have option to change hard drives boot sequence. I have Ubuntu & Windows installed on same HD.

Comment: So, the question say, you can only boot Windows but not Ubuntu. Your comment says you cannot boot Windows. Which one is it? Can you clear that up, please? It would be good, if you [edit] your question to clarify this contradiction and include the BootRepair link. Having every relevant piece of information in once place makes it much easier for potential helpers and comments can be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with boot-repair that it could not recognize windows and it was just Ubuntu option on purple screen but `sudo update-grub` worked for me.